# Create list of Approvers Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create an application where you can create project-based expenses, and each project should have a list of approvers who will approve the expense once uploaded to the project, how do I replicate this in Django.

What I tried to do.
I got the approvers into the form as a ModelMultipleChoiceField

```
self.fields['approvers'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Profile.objects.all())
```

and saved it as a list into the database

```
def getApprovers(approvers):
    id = []
    for profile in approvers:
        id.append(profile.id)
    return id
```

in project create function

```
 project.approvers = getApprovers(form.cleaned_data['approvers'])
```

I created a templatetag to display the list of approvers as the Profile Queryset objects. I tried to iterate over the saved list of approvers, but I keep getting errors

```
def approvers_list(approvers):
    
    for profile in list(approvers):
     profiles = [Profile.objects.filter(pk = i) for i in
```

list(approvers)]
return profile
I got this error

> Field 'id' expected a number but got '['.

This is the result I got after changing the approvers_list method

```
def approvers_list(approvers):
    p = []
    for profile in list(approvers):
       p.append(profile)
        
    return p
```

This is the result

> ['[', '1', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '3', ']']

How can I turn this into a list of ids, so I can use it to get individual profiles of the approvers?

How can I get this to work best?

Here are the models

```
class Project(MiscClass):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    approvers = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, validators=[int_list_validator])
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Expense(MiscClass):
    PROCESSING = 1
    APPROVED = 2
    DECLINED = 3
    
    APPROVAL_STATUS = (
        (PROCESSING, 'Processing'),
        (APPROVED, 'Approved'),
        (DECLINED, 'Declined')
    )
    
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300 , null=True, unique=True)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=APPROVAL_STATUS, default=PROCESSING)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    refrence_number = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_due = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    merchant = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    expense_date =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super(Expense, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: If you are getting errors, can you put the traceback as well?

Comment: I already edited it so you can understand the problem better